# .net Core - After adding an API with JWT MVC sign in no longer working

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a .Net Core 2.0 application that I have added an API to.  I'm using JWT to Authenticate requests and it is working nicely.

After going back to the MVC portion of my application, the login process seems to be no longer working.  _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...) works, but SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) (from the view) is FALSE.

This is the result from _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...):

? result 
{Succeeded}
    IsLockedOut: false
    IsNotAllowed: false
    RequiresTwoFactor: false
    Succeeded: true

The User and claims seem to not be set properly.  Here is how they look right after Sign in (breakpoint in view):

? User.Identities.First()
{System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity}
    Actor: null
    AuthenticationType: null
    BootstrapContext: null
    Claims: Count = 0
    CustomSerializationData: null
    IsAuthenticated: false
    Label: null
    Name: null
    NameClaimType: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
    RoleClaimType: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

I tried with a different (new) user, but same results.

Also if I try to connect to a secure page I get a 401, but not redirected to the Login page.

Did I break my routine somehow? hmmm not sure where to look.

**Update:**  This may be my problem...

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Jwt";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Jwt";
        }).AddJwtBearer("Jwt", options => ...
```

I think this is forcing my non-api controllers to look for a JWT Token which has not been provided.  I just need to figure out how to do both COOKIE and JWT in the same app.

Tried adding this to my api controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) ]
```

When I add that, I get an Internal server error back on API requests and so does this line:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have JWT and with Cookie Authentication completely working, but I have moved past this particular problem... so I'll go ahead and answer this specific question, then open another question for for the next issue.

The short answer is to comment out the lines listed in ConfigureServices.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Jwt";
            //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Jwt";
        })
```

If you set JWT as the default Auth Scheme, that breaks the cookie scheme in MVC.  Once I commented out these lines Login and the rest of cookie authentication works fine.

I did still have some issues with JWT but I'll deal with that in another question.

I'm using this in API controllers to hook up JWT Auth.

```
[Route("API/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```